# There is no method 'GetResults' on type 'Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.QueryableExtensions' that matches the specified arguments

Tags: content-search, solr

We are using Solr for indexing. We recently upgraded from Sitecore version 8.1 update 2 to 8.2 update 5. After upgrading when a search is performed we get the following error:

> There is no method 'GetResults' on type
>   'Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.QueryableExtensions' that matches the
>   specified arguments

Here is the relevant code:

```
var csmIndex = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(index);
using (var context = csmIndex.CreateSearchContext(Sitecore.ContentSearch.Security.SearchSecurityOptions.DisableSecurityCheck))
{
    var query = context.GetQueryable<CustomSearchResult>();
    query = query.Where(i => i.SearchContent.Contains(search) || i.SearchTitle.Contains(search) || i.Url.Contains(search));
    if(facilityID != default(ID))
    {
        query = query.Where(i => i.FacilityId == facilityID);
    }

    query = query.Page(page - 1, pageSize);
    var items = query.GetResults();
}
```

I decompiled `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.dll` and verified the method exists. I am getting no compliation errors.  I'm not sure what has changed between versions that would cause this.

Comment: Is your Solr instance running and accessible? I had a support ticket for a similar error recently, except it was for the FacetOn method. The response from support was that it was due to Solr not being available.

Comment: Yes, I can connect to the Solr Admin in my browser and see the core. I'm also able to rebuild the index within Sitecore.

Comment: Could you share your CustomSearchResult model?

Comment: This actually appears to be environmental. Solr is crashing because it's looking for a segment file in the sitecore_suggested_test_index that doesn't exist.

Comment: We also had this error on two of our development servers. At first I checked and verified DLL versions, .NET Runtime versions, etc. and assumed that the problem is to find there. After a while I found this thread and checked the SOLR instance which was offline. So if you also encounter this error, **make sure to check your SOLR instance**. The error message here is just very bad.

Answer (score 7):

I recently contacted Sitecore support regarding this and a few other issues with Solr.

Regarding your exception I got this answer:

> The error is related to the fact that Solr provider is not
>   initialized before extracting GetResults() method. And it can happen
>   in two cases:
>
> 1. When Solr is turned off before starting of Sitecore
> 2. Due to the possible delays in  pipeline which can be before initializing Solr provider.
>
> Regarding the first case, please note, that this exception only the result, not the cause of the missing connection to Solr, and does not affect Sitecore functionality in any way.
>
> Regarding the second case please try to change the order of processors in the initialize pipeline in a following way. It should prevent the appearing of such errors due to delays in initialize pipeline.

Here is the patch that I prapared for this second case:

```
<sitecore>
  <pipelines>
    <initialize>
      <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeSolrProvider, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
        <patch:delete />
      </processor>
      <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeSolrProvider, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeScheduler, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
    </initialize>
  </pipelines>
</sitecore>
```

We test it on UAT, but so far this exception is gone.

Comment: #1 was my issue. Restarted IIS on my local, while the Solr service running, the `GetResults()` error went away

Comment: what config file would that pipelines XML snippet go into?

Comment: you can put that into the new config patch.

Answer (score 2):

After digging deeper it turns out that the they are using Solr version 5.5.0. This appears to be leading to the known issue identified in the [Solr compatibility table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897).

We'll see what happens after upgrading Solr.

Comment: so was this the fix? what happened next? (you can accept your own answer btw)

Answer (score 2):

This could also be shown when your `ServiceBaseAddress` is wrong in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config`

I had to change my address from `https://xxx/solr/` to `https://xxx/solr` (removed the last /)