# Error Log : "There is no method 'Filter' on type...” while migrating Sitecore version

Tags: content-search, migration

This is not a duplicate of: 
[There is no method 'GetResults' on type 'Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.QueryableExtensions' that matches the specified arguments](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8915/there-is-no-method-getresults-on-type-sitecore-contentsearch-linq-queryableex)

because the patch applied is already included in Sitecore 9.

Also our exception is really on "Filter" rather than "GetResults" :

ERROR There is no method 'Filter' on type 'Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.QueryableExtensions' that matches the specified arguments
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: There is no method 'Filter' on type 'Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.QueryableExtensions' that matches the specified arguments
Source: System.Core
   at System.Linq.EnumerableRewriter.FindMethod(Type type, String name, ReadOnlyCollection`1 args, Type[] typeArgs, BindingFlags flags)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableRewriter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.OldExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionList(ReadOnlyCollection`1 original)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableRewriter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.OldExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionList(ReadOnlyCollection`1 original)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableRewriter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.OldExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionList(ReadOnlyCollection`1 original)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableRewriter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.OldExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionList(ReadOnlyCollection`1 original)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableRewriter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.OldExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionList(ReadOnlyCollection`1 original)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableRewriter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.OldExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionList(ReadOnlyCollection`1 original)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableRewriter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableExecutor`1.Execute()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.QueryableExtensions.GetResults[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)

We're migrating from 8.2 to 9. I now have this error:

```
There is no method 'Filter' on type 'Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.QueryableExtensions' that matches the specified arguments.
```

I do see some people confronted to what must be a sibling "There is no method 'GetResults' on type 'Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.QueryableExtensions'

so I'm looking into this, but will still take some advice.

Thank you!